# Re-create a bookmark bar link with functionality similar to the "Pin-it" button

Tags: javascript, button, web-scraping, pinterest

I would like to recreate a button similar to the pinterest pin-it button for my own personal use. When I say pin-it button im referring to the button pinterest has you drag into you're bookmark bar upon registering. When clicked this button pulls all the images from a page and gives you a option to type a small blurb. If I had to guess how they do it id say there scraping the entire page and then parsing the data for IMG tags?

If anyone has a example or sample of how to create a button with similar functionality that would be above and beyond what im looking for , but im sure id be happy with just a brief explaination of how to accomplish such functionality. Im sure I can figure it out from there.